# Redux state is undefined in mapStateToProps with two stores

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux

I have two react apps which each has it's own redux store (inside ASP.Net Core, but I don't think that's relevant). I found that I had quite a lot of duplicate code between the two apps so I made a `Ui.Common` Project for the shared code between the two projects. In that scope I introduced a `commonStore` that each of the two apps uses as well as their own store.
As per the docs I initialize the `commonStore` on it's own React-Context and the `connect` calls reference that same context when the `commonStore` is required. For the initialization of the stores I do:

```
const store = ReduxStore.configureStore(history);
const commonStore = CommonStore.configureStore();
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Provider store={commonStore} context={CommonContext}>
            <ConnectedRouter history={history} children={routes} />
        </Provider>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('react-app')
);
```

Config for the `CommonStore`

```
public configureStore() {
    const windowIfDefined = typeof window === 'undefined' ? null : window as any;
    // If devTools is installed, connect to it
    const devToolsExtension = windowIfDefined && windowIfDefined.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ as () => StoreEnhancer;
    const createStoreWithMiddleware = compose(devToolsExtension ? devToolsExtension() : <S>(next: StoreEnhancerStoreCreator<S>) => next)(createStore);
    const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(rootReducer()) as Store<CommonAppState>;
    return store;
}
```

And these are my "helper" methods for interacting with the `commonStore`:

```
export function rootReducer(): Reducer<CommonAppState> {
    return combineReducers<CommonAppState>({
        app: appReducer,
        userSettings: userSettingsReducer
    });
}

export const CommonContext = React.createContext<ReactReduxContextValue>(undefined);

/** A connect wrapper to connect specifically to the common redux store. */
export function commonConnect(mapStateToProps?, mapDispatchToProps?, mergeProps?, options?: ConnectOptions) {
    if (!options) {
        options = {};
    }
    options.context = CommonContext;
    return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, mergeProps, options);
}
```

In one of the apps (`Ui.WebApp`) this works as expected, the two stores work independently and everything is nice.

In the second app (`Ui.Management`) the `commonConnect` doesn't seem to work correctly. In the redux dev-tools I can see that the store is there, gets initialized and has a default initial state. Also, the dispatches (from `mapDispatchToProps`) I execute on the store are there and update the store accordingly.
But in every single `mapStateToProps` the state is always `undefined`.

Most of the components consuming the `commonStore` actually "live" in `Ui.Common` and as they work in `Ui.WebApp` but not in `Ui.Management`, the problem most likely is not located within the `Ui.Common` project.

The two partial reducers definitely have their `default` set, as otherwise it wouldn't work in any of the two apps.

Comment: Have you tried creating a minimal, reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Can you show part of Ui.Management how you exactly incorporate common module?

Answer (score 1):

Think about creating an extendible store to aggregate the common store with the custom one. Try implementing a function that takes custom reducers as params and aggregate them with the commons.
I tried a similar solution and it work easily instantiating only one `rect-redux Provider`.
Something like:

```js
const createMyStore = (customReducers) => createStore(
  combineReducers({
    common: commonReducer,
    ...customReducers
  });
);
```

Tell me if the solution works fine for you.